# Wso2 API Manager ERROR_CODE = 101508, Error in Sender

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I publised one test API on WSO2 API Manager as prototype API. But When I am trying to curl the API endpoint I am getting bellow error

`curl http://localhost:8280/weather2/v1.0.0`

```
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
   <am:code>101508</am:code>
   <am:type>Status report</am:type>
   <am:message>Runtime Error</am:message>
   <am:description>Error in Sender</am:description>
</am:fault>
```

I am getting the same error for Managed API as well.

Comment: Error code suggest connection time out. What's your backend?

Comment: Backend is http://api.mydubaitrip.com/weathers

Comment: You can enable HTTP wire log in the API Manager, by uncommenting `log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG` line in repository/conf/log4j.properties file. You can see how API Manager sends the request to backend, what's the response.

Comment: Hi @AbimaranKugathasan, I know this is a very old thread on the issue. I have uncommented the wire in debug but logs are not generating in DEBUG. Am I missing something in the steps to enable the wire to debug? Appreciate your kind response.

Answer (score 1):

There is existing issue which cause this behavior[]. However you can create a custom sequence as below and add it as a insequencefor the API in manage API phase. The issue was, without below sequence the host header going to endpoint as`Host: api.mydubaitrip.com:80` which is not supported by that endpoint.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="remove_port_In"> 
      <property name="REQUEST_HOST_HEADER" value="api.mydubaitrip.com" scope="axis2"/>
</sequence>
```

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-4429